# storing the RDBMS table data through lucene in text file on hard disk

Tags: lucene

I want to store the RDBMS sql query result of 3.2 million records in text file using lucene and then search that.
[I saw the example here [how to integrate RAMDirectory into FSDirectory in lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913180/how-to-integrate-ramdirectory-into-fsdirectory-in-lucene][1])

[1]: [how to integrate RAMDirectory into FSDirectory in lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913180/how-to-integrate-ramdirectory-into-fsdirectory-in-lucene) .I have this piece of code that is working for me

```
  public class lucetest {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            lucetest lucetestObj = new lucetest();
            lucetestObj.main1(lucetestObj);
        }

        public void main1(lucetest lucetestObj) {
            final File INDEX_DIR = new File(
                    "C:\\Documents and Settings\\44444\\workspace\\lucenbase\\bin\\org\\lucenesample\\index");

            try {
                Connection conn;
                Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver").newInstance();
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:teradata://x.x.x.x/CHARSET=UTF16", "aaa", "bbb");
                StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_35);

//              Directory index = new RAMDirectory(); //To use RAM space
Directory index = FSDirectory.open(INDEX_DIR); //To use Hard disk,This will not consume RAM

                IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_35,
                        analyzer);
                IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(index, config);

                // IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(INDEX_DIR, analyzer, true);
                System.out.println("Indexing to directory '" + INDEX_DIR + "'...");

                lucetestObj.indexDocs(writer, conn);
                writer.optimize();
                writer.close();
                System.out.println("pepsi");
                lucetestObj.searchDocs(index, analyzer, "india");
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {

            }

        }

        void indexDocs(IndexWriter writer, Connection conn) throws Exception {
            String sql = "select id, name, color from pet";

            String queryy = "  SELECT  CFMASTERNAME, " + "  ULTIMATEPARENTID,"
                    + "ULTIMATEPARENT, LONG_NAMEE FROM  XCUST_SRCH_SRCH"
                    + "sample 100000;";
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryy);
            int kk = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                Document d = new Document();
                d.add(new Field("id", rs.getString("CFMASTERID"), Field.Store.YES,
                        Field.Index.NO));
                d.add(new Field("name", rs.getString("CFMASTERNAME"),
                        Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
                d.add(new Field("color", rs.getString("LONG_NAMEE"),
                        Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
                writer.addDocument(d);
            }
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        }

        void searchDocs(Directory index, StandardAnalyzer analyzer,
                String searchstring) throws Exception {

            String querystr = searchstring.length() > 0 ? searchstring : "lucene";
            Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_35, "name", analyzer)
                    .parse(querystr);

            int hitsPerPage = 10;
            IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(index);
            IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
            TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(
                    hitsPerPage, true);
            searcher.search(q, collector);
            ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
            System.out.println("Found " + hits.length + " hits.");
            for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; ++i) {
                int docId = hits[i].doc;
                Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
                System.out.println((i + 1) + ".CFMASTERNAME " + d.get("name")
                        + " ****LONG_NAMEE**" + d.get("color") + "****ID******"
                        + d.get("id"));
            }

            searcher.close();
        }
    }
```

How to format this code so that instead of RAM directory the sql result table is saved on the hard disk at the path specified.I am not able to work out a solution.My requirement is that this table data stored on disk through lucene returns result very fast.Hence i am saving data on disk through lucene which is indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Directory index = FSDirectory.open(INDEX_DIR);
```

You mention saving the sql result to a text file, but that is unnecessary overhead. As you iterate through a ResultSet, save the rows directly to the Lucene index.

As an aside, not that it matters much, but naming your local var (final or otherwise) in all caps is against the convention. Use camelCase. All caps is only for class-level constants (static final members of a class).

Comment: Hi Mark,where should the statement Directory index = FSDirectory.open(INDEX_DIR); be put in the code.Please explain.

Comment: Exactly where you already have Directory index = ... in your code. Just replace the right-hand side.

Comment: This is working nicely.Thankyou very much Marko.It makes multiple files in the path given.The query is returning results within 1 second.I am now finding which fields to be indexed and which to be not.I have also tried multi field query and single field query with lucene search and working well.

Comment: Hopefully it will be way under one second and closer to 10-20 ms :)